# Drop Down in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When I add a controller with Entity Framework, it produces views but it misses the fields like Teacher, and Student, It only creates the ProjectName and Discription fields and views. What I want is a drop down having data from student and teacher table. The tutorial of MusicStore at Microsoft Virtual Acadmey wrote the same code and drop down appeared but I am having problem.

(I am a newbie to MVC pattern)
compile the code and run it

Project.cs (Modal Class)

```
{
    public class Project
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int StudentID { get; set; }
        public int TeachersID { get; set; }
        public string ProjectName { get; set; }
        public Teachers Teachers { get; set; }
        public Student Student1 { get; set; }
        public Student Student2 { get; set; }
        public Student Student3 { get; set; }
        public string Discription { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Controller

```
using DataCollection.Models;

namespace DataCollection.Controllers
{
    public class ProjectsController : Controller
    {
        private DataCollectionContext db = new DataCollectionContext();

        // GET: Projects
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Projects.ToList());
        }

        // GET: Projects/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Project project = db.Projects.Find(id);
            if (project == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(project);
        }

        // GET: Projects/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Projects/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,ProjectName,Discription")] Project project)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Projects.Add(project);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(project);
        }

        // GET: Projects/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Project project = db.Projects.Find(id);
            if (project == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(project);
        }

        // POST: Projects/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "ID,ProjectName,Discription")] Project project)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(project).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(project);
        }

        // GET: Projects/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Project project = db.Projects.Find(id);
            if (project == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(project);
        }

        // POST: Projects/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            Project project = db.Projects.Find(id);
            db.Projects.Remove(project);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

and my view is as follow

```
@model IEnumerable<DataCollection.Models.Project>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ProjectName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Discription)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProjectName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Discription)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Teacher Modal

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace DataCollection.Models
{
    public class Teachers
    {
        public int TeachersID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100,ErrorMessage ="Enter First Name")]
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Enter Last Name")]
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string LName { get; set; }

        //[Display(Name = "First Name")]
        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Enter Designation")]
        public string Designation { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Project Evulation Committee")]
        public Boolean PREC { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Evaluation Committee")]
        public Boolean EC { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Project Coordinator")]
        public Boolean ProjCoordinator { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Project> Project { get; set; }
    }
}
```

(comments are welcome, Thanks)

Comment: Include your controller and view code as well.

Comment: I would also provide the model definitions for 'Teachers' and 'Student'

Comment: If the MVC scaffolding missed a model property, you sometimes need to add them manually. You do have the option, to create a partial view for your Teachers / Student models and then use them in your main view there.

Comment: Not sure why the difference, but I'd note that you shouldn't rely on scaffolding.  Think of it as a "Quick Start".  It gets the basics setup for you, but there's alot of decisions to be made about how to display/edit the more complicated things.  I personally never use scaffolding anymore, a it results in more code I end up replacing then using.

Comment: i deleted mt controller and view and clean the build data then added the controller same error, scaffolding not working...  virtual view (i dont know how it works) but it will be mess !!